# FFMPEG merging videos Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1

Tags: ffmpeg

When i use this command it in generally works with no issues but I get this warning and the video is super long (should be 20 or 30 seconds and is 24 minutes)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i manual.txt -c copy C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\manual_merge\asdf.mp4
```

this is the output from the command promp

```
[mp4 @ 000001b34d593fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 608569, current: 12201; changing to 608570. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

how do i fix this warning?